# テーブルから得た List が外部キーだけ持っているが、そのキー（id）に対応するデータを取得し、 thymeleaf で HTML(view) に表示したい

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

**環境**
・eclipse (spring tool suite 4)
・spring
・thymeleaf
・MySQL

以下のようなテーブルがあります

[image: 2tables]

---

これを以下の記述で book category id のまま表示することはできました。

Model: Books

```
package librarypackage.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Books implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column(name="book_category_id")
  private int bookCategoryId;

  private String name;

  ...略
}
```

Model: Book category

```
package librarypackage.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="book_category")
public class BookCategory implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private int id;

  private String category;

  ...略
```

BooksRepository

```
package onepackage.repositories;

import onepackage.model.Books;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BooksRepository extends JpaRepository<Books, Long> {

}
```

Controller: Books

```
package onepackage.controller;

import onepackage.model.Books;

import onepackage.repositories.BooksRepository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class BooksController {
    
    @Autowired
    private BooksRepository booksRepository;
    

    @GetMapping("/books")
    public String getBooks(Model model) {
        List<Books> books = booksRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("booklist", books);
        return "books";
    }
}
```

View

```
...略
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>本の名前</th>
            <th>カテゴリ</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="books : ${booklist}">
            <td th:text="${books.id}">a</td>
            <td th:text="${books.name}">b</td>
            <td th:text="${books.bookCategoryId}">c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
...略
```

こうすると表示は

[image: output table]

となります。
`${booklist}`には category id の情報しかないわけですが、テーブルのカテゴリのところを id でなくて、対応するカテゴリ(の文字列)を表示したいのですが、どういった方法があるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
create table book_category (
  id integer primary key,
  category varchar(255)
);

create table book (
  id integer primary key,
  book_category_id integer,
  name varchar(255),
  foreign key (book_category_id) references book_category(id)
);
```

のように外部キー制約が付くテーブルの関係は、 JPA では次のように記述します。

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Books implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private BookCategory bookCategory;

    private String name;

    // ...略
}
```

これに合わせてThymeleafテンプレートも変更します:

```html
      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="books : ${booklist}">
          <td th:text="${books.id}">a</td>
          <td th:text="${books.name}">b</td>
          <td th:text="${books.bookCategory.category}">c</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

[サンプルコード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso73625)([差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/af921fb9b3f2ec91c43cd1e48a54779e5039e6ab))

Comment: Entity で クラスを作るのですね。

Comment: \@ManyToOne に加えて \@JoinColumn も必要そうです。

Comment: [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68382/2808)でもJPA Mappingの話題について回答しているのですが、 そちらに記載している通り、`@ManyToOne`  のデフォルト戦略は join-colomun なので必須というわけではありません。ただし、例えば外部キーの命名がJPAデフォルト(今回の場合であれば`book_category_id`)に従っていない場合は、明示的に外部キーの名前を指定する必要があったりはします。(JSR-338  2.10.3.2)